# how to place buttons in my custom view?

Tags: java, android, button, gridview

I have created a gridlayout with width=3 and height =2. i placed 6 views in each grid element with ids as view1,view2,view3,view4,view5 and view 6. now how to place buttons on each view programmatically?

```
    View child1,child2,child3,child4,child5,child6;
    child1=(View)view.findViewById(R.id.view1);
    child2=(View)view.findViewById(R.id.view2);
    child3=(View)view.findViewById(R.id.view3);
    child4=(View)view.findViewById(R.id.view4);
    child5=(View)view.findViewById(R.id.view5);
    child6=(View)view.findViewById(R.id.view6);
```

and finally to place dynamic buttons i used the code as below.

```
 child1 = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.video,null);
                        video = (Button)child1.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

this continues for child2,3 etc.video is an xml layout with a button id as button.

the layout is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#484848"
        android:layout_weight=".1">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imb1"
            android:layout_weight=".07"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7.5dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/back"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="#484848" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#484848"
            android:src="@drawable/medilearn1"
            android:layout_weight=".15"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Dashboard"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fbfbfb"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.67" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Restart"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight=".07"
            android:background="#d86018"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="7.5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7.5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d8d8d8"
    android:layout_weight=".9">
    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:queryHint="search"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#d8d8d8">
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:id="@+id/gridView">
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/view1" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/view2" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/view3" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/view4" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/view5" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/view6" />

    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#484848"
        android:layout_weight=".1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Version:1.0"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fbfbfb"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


   </LinearLayout>
```

This is my layout.

I found the solution. I declared linearlayout in each grid with hight and width as my wish and called child with addView().so,

```
LinearLayout lay1=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
```

and then

```
lay1.addView(child1);
```

Comment: make custom gridview with arrayAdapter and separate gridview row xml

Comment: sorry,i can't understand.can u please give me an example.@Aditi

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Button to your view like this:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
btn.setId(1);
btn.setText("ButtonText");

yourView.addView(btn);
```

If you want it to fill your whole view, replace `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` with `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`.

Comment: No this is not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

just set adapter for your GridView

```
MyGridAdapter csAdapter = new MyGridAdapter();
    csGridView.setAdapter(csAdapter);
    csGridView.setOnItemClickListener(gridItemClicked);
```

and adapter code is

```
public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener gridItemClicked = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

//your code 

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:
Based on the layout you posted there are two options you can pursue:

1. Create the layout in your xml file: you could just replace the `View` tags with `Button` tags if your layout is static and will always require those buttons.
2. Create the layout dynamically: for this you don't need the `View` tags inside your layout as those will be created programmatically, so you can remove those. Then do the following for every `Button` you want to create (I'm assuming the layout containing the buttons is called `video.xml`):

   ```
   View child = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.video,null);
   GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
   // set the row number this child is located in
   params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowNum, 1);
   // set the column number this child is located in
   params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(colNum, 1);
   child.setLayoutParams(params);
   grid.addView(child);
   ```

Also, please note that a `View` cannot have a child `View`, only layouts extending `ViewGroup` (e.g. `FrameLayout`, `GridLayout`, ...) can have child `View`s!

---

The best way to inflate the `View` in your case is the following code:

```
GridLayout grid = view.findViewById(R.id.grid); // get the grid layout
// ...
child1 = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.video, grid, true);
video = (Button)child1.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

By providing the parent (`grid`), the `LayoutInflator` will take care of properly inflating the requested resource into the view hierarchy, the `true` attaches the inflated layout to the root layout.

Also check the API docs for this:

> [`inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)):
>   Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource.

Comment: it's not working.i wanted to put dynamic buttons in 3*2 grid and three buttons should fill the entire row,in each cases. i used grid.addView(child),where child is a view. But it was not giving me what i want. so i created 6 custom view(3 in each row) and i want to put buttons in it. if u have better solution for this plz suggest.@TR4Android

Comment: What are you using as your root layout? A `GridView`, `GridLayout` or something else entirely?

Comment: And if I understand correctly you want to put `Button`s inside the `View` elements of `GridLayout`, right?